# ajax form options from mysql results as button that can set a value in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form that selects an option and loads data from a mysql database. These results show in boxes. I would like the boxes to be bootstrap buttons and when one is clicked it adds the values to a textfield and changes if a different one i selected. I have tried to nothing working

the html/php file code is :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Loading MySQL Records on Drop Down Selection using PHP jQuery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
select{

 width:250px;
 padding:5px;
 border-radius:3px;
}
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>/* jquery code will be here */</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

     <div class="page-header">
        <h3>
        <select id="getProducts">
        <option value="showAll" selected="selected">Show All Products</option>
        <?php
        require_once 'config.php';

        $stmt = $dbcon->prepare('SELECT * FROM categories');
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($row);
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        </h3>
        </div>
    <blockquote>Load MySQL Records On Drop Down Selection</blockquote>
    <hr />

    <div class="" id="display">
       <!-- Records will be displayed here -->
    </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The js is :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{  
 // function to get all records from table
 function getAll(){

  $.ajax
  ({
   url: 'getproducts.php',
   data: 'action=showAll',
   cache: false,
   success: function(r)
   {
    $("#display").html(r);
   }
  });   
 }

 getAll();
 // function to get all records from table


 // code to get all records from table via select box
 $("#getProducts").change(function()
 {    
  var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();

  var dataString = 'action='+ id;

  $.ajax
  ({
   url: 'getproducts.php',
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(r)
   {
    $("#display").html(r);
   } 
  });
 })
 // code to get all records from table via select box
});
</script>
```

and the getProducts.php is :

```
    <?php

 include('config.php');

 $action = $_REQUEST['action'];

 if($action=="showAll"){

  $stmt=$dbcon->prepare('SELECT product_id, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_name');
  $stmt->execute();

 }else{

  $stmt=$dbcon->prepare('SELECT product_id, product_name FROM products WHERE cat_id=:cid ORDER BY product_name');
  $stmt->execute(array(':cid'=>$action));
 }

 ?>
 <div class="row">
 <?php
 if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

  while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   extract($row);

   ?>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
   <div style="border-radius:3px; border:#cdcdcd solid 1px; padding:22px;"><?php echo $product_name; ?></div><br />
   </div>
   <?php  
  }

 }else{

  ?>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
   <div style="border-radius:3px; border:#cdcdcd solid 1px; padding:22px;"><?php echo $product_name; ?></div><br />
  </div>
        <?php  
 }


 ?>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance